# Capturing Nightwatch incremental screenshots

Tags: nightwatch.js

Right now doScreenshot overwrites the old image but I'd like to be able to do. doScreenshot('screenshots/1.png'+day+time)

Any advice on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for it [here](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch/blob/master/nightwatch.conf.js)